# Is there any modern course like Bourbaki's books? (Including Category Theory)

Tags: reference-request

I would like to have something like Bourbaki's or Landau's collection of books. However, Bourbaki failed the aim to build all from the mathematics foundation since they did not use (are not using) the Category Theory, and in fact, the Set Theory that they use as fundament actually is wrong.

So, is there any collection of books like Bourbaki's but including Category Theory?

Thank you all :D

Comment: I like your question, but I don't understand one thing. Why have you said Bourbaki's set theory is wrong? I have heard it is different from ZF, NBG and others, but WRONG... I mean, the are Bourbaki. It's difficult to me believe they published a book with a wrong theory.

Comment: I saw it today reading on internet, but really i have not read it all:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929303/is-the-bourbaki-treatment-of-set-theory-outdated

Comment: I suppose you mean Mikhail Katz's answer. It is the unique that asserts that. Zavosh's answer for example says ''This is what he means by Bourbaki's neglect of Gödel, not that Bourbaki's Set Theory is inconsistent, but that it's not an in-depth treatise on mathematical logic.''. Anyway, I dont' want to polemicize because I'm not a set theorist and I have no idea about Bourbaki's book. It was just because your comment surprises me, nothing else. A greeting.