# Bourbaki: Quantification Expansion

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, math-history, meta-math

I'm reading *Theory of Sets* where existential quantification is defined:

a)
$$
\exists x R = (\tau_x(R)|x)R
$$

and I have questions regarding the expansion for an example relation:

b)
$$
\exists y \exists x \in x y
$$

using the definition to expand.  Link bars are placed over and between symbols $\tau_{\alpha} \rightarrow \square_{\alpha}$.  $\alpha$ is only used in this post to identify the initial and final point of the link bar.  If the link bars are added on top of the symbols, $\alpha$ can be removed.

c)
$$
\exists y (\in (\tau_x \in \square_x y) y)
$$
Use definition (a) for $\exists y$:
$$
y_{sub} = \tau_y \in (\tau_x \in \square_x \square_y) \square_y
$$
and the resulting expression:

d)
$$
(\in (\tau_{x_1} \in \square_{x_1} (\tau_{y_1} \in (\tau_{x_2} \in \square_{x_2} \square_{y_1}) \square_{y_1})) (\tau_{y_2} \in (\tau_{x_3} \in \square_{x_3} \square_{y_2}) \square_{y_2}))
$$

$\tau_x(R)$ represents a [fully qualified](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225841/bourbaki-universal-quantification-interpretation) object such that $R$ holds.  If there is no such object, then $\tau_x(R)$ represents an arbitrary object.  In the latter case, such an arbitrary object would cause $R$ to be false.

**Question**
Does the final form (d) look correct?  I have doubts because the outer most choice operators $\tau_{x_1}$ and $\tau_{y_2}$ may result in different values which may not hold for the expression $\in x y$.  For instance, the sub-expression starting with $\tau_{y_1}$ and $\tau_{y_2}$ is the same, but the link bars are self contained to each sub-expression, meaning $y$ may hold for multiple values, which may not correspond to $x$.

I think either form (d) is incorrect or Bourbaki intended that duplicate $\tau_x$ linked expressions all choose the same value.  In the later case, it seems one would have to search the expression for duplicates somehow.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
The form (d) above is correct and if there are duplicate $\tau$ expressions the choice operator must choose the same for $\square$.

Comment: Is this using Polish notation? And what is "$\Box_\alpha$"?

Comment: The first of the two expressions under (c) is fine, but I don't get the second one. Where did '$y=$" come from (and where did it go in (d))? In (d), I can see why $x$ has been split into $x_1$ and $x_2$, since each of the two $y$'s gets a $\tau_x$ and you need to keep them distinct. But there should be only one $\tau_y$, coming from the $\exists y$ in (c).

Comment: @Nick Where did I "mention only a single $y$"? The closest thing to that in my comment is "only one $\tau_y$".

Comment: @Nick OK, I get it. You generate a single $\tau$ expression for $y$ but then you have to substitute that for both of the $y$'s, and your subscript convention leads to different subscripts in those two places (where Bourbaki's connecting lines would look identical in both places).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hyper long comment*

IMO, Bourbaki's cumbersome notation (squares and links) is only needed in order to define the usual concepts of scope and binding of a quantifier.

The $\tau$ operator is exactly like the set-builder one: $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$; when applied to a formula with $x$ free produces a *term*, i.e. the name of an object.

In the same way, we have that [page 20]:

> if $B$ is an assertion and $x$ a letter, then $\tau_x(B)$ is an object. [When used with] an assertion $B$ that expresses a property of an object $x$, it represents a distinguished object which has that property, if such an object exists.

Bourbaki uses it to define the quantifiers, and specifically: $\exists x A := (\tau_x (A) \mid x)A$, which we can write as: $A[\tau_x(A) /x]$.

What happens with a double quantification $\exists y \exists x R(x,y)$?

We have to keep track of the formula to which we apply the $\tau$ operator; thus, with the first choice, the operator is not relative to formula $R(x,y)$ but to formula $S(y)=\exists x R(x,y)$, where **only** $y$ is free.

In order to keep track of the formula $A$ to which the $\tau$ operator applies, I'll use $\tau_x^A$.

Thus, the first step will produce: $\exists x R(x,\tau_y^S)$, and the second step will produce:

> $R(\tau_x^R,\tau_y^S)$.

*In conclusion, IMO we have to consider not different variables $x_1,x_2$, but different formulas*.

Now, going back to your example, we have that $R$ is $\in$ and thus: $\in(\tau_x^R,\tau_y^S)$, but what $\tau_x^R$ and $\tau_y^S$ look like?

$\tau_y^S$ will be $\tau_y(\exists x \in(x,y))$, and thus: $(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)$. Does it work? I think so, because the formula $\exists x \in (x, y)$ has only $y$ free, and thus we can correctly apply the $\tau$ operator (that will bind it).

Up to now, we have "reduced" the original formula to $\in (\tau_x^R, (\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y))$.

The second step will apply $\tau$ operator to $\exists x R(x,\tau_y^S)$, i.e. to $\exists x \in (x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y))$.

Formula $R$ is $\in (x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))$ and again it has only $x$ free: the second and third occurrences of $x$ are bound and thus we cannot use them in the substitution process (we can rewrite them with $z$ and nothing will change).

Thus, again, we have the term $\tau_x[\in (\square_x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))]$ that we have to replace in place of $x$ into $R$ to get:

> $\in (\tau_x[\in (\square_x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))],(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))$.

---

*Now, we have to try to read it*...

According to the semantics of the $\tau$ operator, the term $\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)$ represents a distinguished objcet that has property $\exists x \in (x, y)$, if any. But this amounts to saying that it represents a non-empty set.

Assuming a "naive" set universe with only two sets: $\emptyset$ and $\mathcal P(\emptyset)$, the formula $\exists x \in (x, y)$ is satisfied by $\mathcal P(\emptyset)$, and thus we may choose it as value for $\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)$.

The second step is obvious: $\tau_x[\in (\square_x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))]$ represents a distinguished object that satisfy formula $\in (x, \mathcal P(\emptyset))$ and thus we may choose $\emptyset$ as value for it.

In conclusion, in our universe formula $\exists y \exists x (x \in y)$ is true because: $\emptyset \in \mathcal P (\emptyset)$.

Comment: I had time to read your answer.  Our final forms agree (see d).  I derived mine from the innermost expressions as I understood the domain of $\tau$ to be the basic signs of the theory vs symbols like $\exists$.  You mention $\{x:\phi(x)\}$ and $\tau_x$ which are slightly different.  It's my understanding the choice op $\tau$ will represent any object if there is no such object that satisfies $R$, while the former set builder will evaluate to $\emptyset$.  This is ok for $\tau$ because the logic value of $\exists x$ depends on what was chosen by $\tau$ substituted in relation $R$.

Comment: My question: In our final form $\in (\tau_x[\in (\square_x,(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))],(\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y)))$ my confusion is the choice operation for the two duplicate forms $Z = (\tau_y \exists x \in (x, \square_y))$.  Both must evaluate to the same value for the final expression to be true.  Do we just assume $Z$ is the same mathematical expression with the same choice made?  If so, I wonder how this works at larger scale.  Does one perform comparisons of the symbols to substitute in the same choice for duplicate expressions everywhere?

Comment: @Nick - IMO, yes, the two "occurrences" must be evaluated at the same time to get the correct result.  And NO, IMO this does **not** work at larger scale. Significantly, there is no use at all in the maybe thousands of pages of Bourbaki's works.

Comment: It appears a way to evaluate is to find every sequence which $\tau_x$ appears and form an equivalence class of positions.  The choice operator $\tau_x$ can then choose a value for each equivalence class.  The value is then substituted back into each position.  Based on my example, I was unsure if there is an optimization to only search if $\in \tau (R_0) \tau (R_1)$.  I'm puzzled why Bourbaki left this out, unless they planned to use higher level math for it later on.