# Bourbaki: Use of tau choice operator?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-history

I have a question about evaluating truth of the sign assemblies in Bourbaki Theory of Sets.

It's my [understanding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062083/bourbaki-quantification-expansion) that when there are duplicate assemblies each starting with the choice operator $\tau$, this operator must *choose* the same value for each linked $\square$ in all duplicate assemblies.  Therefore, to evaluate the truth of a sequence of signs, the sequence must be searched for duplicate sequences starting with $\tau$.

Is it documented elsewhere?  I suspect this is costly, but are there advantages?  Perhaps eliminating the variable name from the form so duplicates can be found?

I have yet to see any Bourbaki documentation on this and am confused by that.

Comment: See ARD Mathias, ["A term of length 4 523 659 424 929" (2002)](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/inefff.pdf)

Comment: Maybe they expected a finite automata (Turing Machine) to recognize or prove, one that does not depend on the theory of their book

Comment: Of course this is documented by Bourbaki. It is essentially the meaning of axiom scheme S7.