# What's the meaning of an axiom in SGA?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, set-theory

In SGA 4-1, Grothendieck stated the following axiom:

($\mathscr{U}$ B) *Soit $R\{x\}$ une relation et $\mathscr{U}$ un univers. S'il existe un élément $y\in\mathscr{U}$ tel que $R\{y\}$, alors $\tau_{x}R\{x\} \in\mathscr{U}$.*

However, I don't know the meaning of the symbols $R\{x\}$ and $\tau_{x}R\{x\}$. I guess that $R\{x\}$ stands for a subset of $x\times x$, since it says that $R\{x\}$ is a relation.

Comment: See [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315595/translating-grothendieck-axiom-ub-into-zfc) for references.

Comment: see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3225841/bourbaki-universal-quantification-interpretation) for the symbol

Comment: In a nuthsell the first one means a relation $R(x)$ (e.g. "x is Rational") while the second one corresponds to existential quantification: $\exists x R(x)$.

Comment: The second is a term, a **selector**, designating *some $x$ such that $R(x)$*, when one exists. Bourbaki uses $\tau$ for this; Hilbert used $\sigma$.